# C# Не удаётся правильно обработать данные. TcpClient. Набор байт. Протокол Майнкрафта

Tags: c#, tcp, byte, protocol, websokets

У майнкрафта есть [свой протокол](https://wiki.vg/Protocol). **Я пытаюсь реализовать сторону клиента.** Версия майнкрафт 1.16.5

*Очень прошу потратить немного времени и прочитать всё что тут написано, вникнуть, и попробовать воспроизвести. **Буду невероятно благодарен!***

Суть протокола в том, что клиент с сервером общаются по TCP протоколу и обмениваются пакетами данных. Как написано в протоколе, пакет в майнкрафте это набор байт который состоит из следующих частей: длина байтов пакета, префикс и содержимое. (Сервер, который можно запустить в один клик на локалке, можно скачать [тут](https://www.minecraft.net/ru-ru/download/server/))

**Пример:** что бы сказать серверу о том, что ты новый клиент, нужно отослать [запрос рукопожатия](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshaking), который включает в себя `номер протокола` (= 754 на версии майнкрафта 1.16.5), `хост`, `порт` и `статус` (= 2 для авторизации).

В коде это будет выглядеть примерно так (для упрощения воспроизведения и точности убрал все свои вспомогательные классы, которые преобразуют значения в байты и обратно):

```
var packetLength    = new byte[] { 16 };            // длина пакета
var prefix          = new byte[] { 0x00 };          // префикс [1 байт]
var protocolVersion = new byte[] { 242, 5 };        // протокол (= 754) [2 байта]
var hostBytesLength = new byte[] { 9 };             // длина байтов хоста [1 байт]
var hostBytes       = new byte[] { 108, 11, 99,     // хост (= "localhost") [9 байт]
                                  97, 108, 104,
                                  11, 115, 116 };   
var port            = new byte[] { 221, 99 };       // порт (= 25565) [2 байта]
var nextState       = new byte[] { 2 };             // состояние [1 байт]

// stream = client.GetStream(), где client = new TcpClient("localhost", 25565)
stream.Write(packetLength,    0, packetLength.Length);
stream.Write(prefix,          0, prefix.Length);
stream.Write(protocolVersion, 0, protocolVersion.Length);
stream.Write(hostBytesLength, 0, hostBytesLength.Length);
stream.Write(hostBytes,       0, hostBytes.Length);
stream.Write(port,            0, port.Length);
stream.Write(nextState,       0, nextState.Length);
```

После этого сервер отправить ответ [0x03](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Set_Compression):

```
// № байта  // значение // описание
[0]         3           длина пакета
[1]         0x03        префикс
[2-3]       128, 2      threshold - максимальный размер пакета (= 256)
```

**Выше всё прекрасно работает.** Мой пакет правильно уходит и правильный пакет приходит. **Проблема в ответе сервера на мой слдующий запрос - запрос авторизации.**

[Запрос авторизации](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login_Start) включает в себя только `имя игрока`. Итак, сам запрос:

```
var packetLength        = new byte[] { 6 };     // длина пакета
var prefix              = new byte[] { 0x00 };  // префикс [1 байт]
var usernameBytesLength = new byte[] { 4 };     // длина байтов имени игрока [1 байт]
var usernameBytes       = new byte[] { 98, 111, // имя игрока (= "bot2") [4 байта]
                                       116, 50 };

stream.Write(packetLength,        0, packetLength.Length);
stream.Write(prefix,              0, prefix.Length);
stream.Write(usernameBytesLength, 0, usernameBytesLength.Length);
stream.Write(usernameBytes,       0, usernameBytes.Length);
```

В ответ я получаю следующее:

```
// № байта  // значение // описание
[0]         23          длина пакета
[1]         0x00        префикс
[2]         0x02        
[3-23]      байты       остальные данные
```

**Что-то не так.** Мне в ответ должен был прийти пакет [0x02](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login_Success), который содержит `16-ти значный uuid` и `имя игрока`, такое же как в запросе. Так же других пакетов 0x00, которые подходят к тем байтам, которые вернул сервер, на википедии не описано.

Я попробовал проигнорировать этот нулевой байт (прочитать, но не учитывать) и тогда всё срослось:

```
// № байта  // значение // описание
[0]         23          длина пакета
[1]         0x00        что-то (проигнорированно)
[2]         0x02        префикс
[3-18]      байты       uuid
[19]        4           длина байтов имени игрока
[20-23]     98, 111,    имя игрока (= "bot2")
            116, 50
```

**ВОПРОС:** почему сервер посылает этот нулевой байт не в попад?

P.S.

Что я пробовал:

- изначально я считал, что длина пакета это всегда 1 байт, однако потом я увидел в википедии, что это [VarInt](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#VarInt_and_VarLong) [1-3 байта](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Packet_format). Для VarInt характерно автоматическое определение длины. Однако читая `new byte { 0x00, 0x02 }`, он считает, что `0x00` - это уже финальное значение. Так что этот вариант отпадает.
- читать поток синхронно, так как предполагал, что данные не успели прочитается или прочитались не верно
- менять версию майнкрафт (тогда нужно передавть соответствующий номер протокола)

Comment: Я думаю, вы не первый, кто пиишет клиента для майнкрафта. Найдите уже написанные open source клиенты и поглядите, как там сделано то, что вам надо.

Comment: Вот вы все показали, а как работаете с сетью не показали, то есть метод, отпраляющий запрос. У меня даже сервак есть на локальной машине, но писать с нуля код, чтобы воспроизвести вашу проблему, меня ломает.

Comment: Вот вам [готовый код](https://github.com/kennyvv/Alex/tree/master/src/Alex.Networking/Java) для работы с MC сервером.

Comment: @aepot  "Вот вы все показали, а как работаете с сетью не показали". При записи в поток данные сразу же передаются клиенту

Comment: Посмотрите код по ссылке, там все есть, я проверил, выглядит более-менее вменяемо. Изучите, допишите свой код с использованием решения на гитхабе.

Comment: @aepot в Алексе слишком много обёрток и невороятно сложно отследить байты конкретного запроса. Также Алекса использует авторизацию, привязанную к учётной записи майнкрафт, а я - нет (разные запросы)

Comment: А никто не обещал, что будет легко, но вы обратите внимание на класс `MinecraftStream` и его зависимости. Это по сути сам движок запросов-ответов.

Comment: @aepot это я понял, сложность в отладки его запросов, ладно, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл описание сего в протоколе. Этот непонятный байт означает длину "упакованного" пакета байт (0 - не упакованный):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]